# Apache Ignite c++ client 2.16. How to handle the connection lost scenarios in the middle of any cache insert/remove/get operations

Tags: ignite, apacheignite

Ignite C++ Thin Clients. The class CacheClient does not throw any ignite errors if the connection is lost during any of the get/remove/contains/insert operations.

Is there an alternative mechanism to handle the connection lost scenarios?

Connection Failover is ok, but if all the cluster connections are lost, how the application will be notified about the situation?